# How to assign current date to scalar variable?

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

I am trying the following syntax to assign current date to one HANA variable for further processing.  I am getting an error

> scalar variable is not allowed

DAY1 is declared as `NVARCHAR(8)` .

```
 DAY1 := SELECT to_nvarchar ((current_date),'YYYYMMDD') from dummy ;
```

Please provide some input .

Comment: What version of HANA?

Comment: Below statement worked ... Yoo.       DAY1 := to_nvarchar(CURRENT_DATE,'yyyymmdd') ;

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
declare DAY1 nvarchar(8);

SELECT to_nvarchar (current_date,'YYYYMMDD') into DAY1 from dummy ;
```

however, if the direct assignment works on your revision, go with that as you safe the parsing & execution of the above SQL statement.

Comment: Hi Lars , SELECT statement doesn't seem to work here . I guess , SELECT is expecting table type as I am getting a message "Scalar Type Not allowed " .  What is your view in this ?

Comment: What error did you get? This definitively works in SQLScript; but not in the SQL Editor - you have to put it into a procedure/function (or a DO BEGIN block starting with SPS 10) to get the SQLScript context.